# INSERT CONCATENAR PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, sql-insert

estou querendo que ao inserir um cadastro no mysql , de acordo com o id ja tenha algo predefinido

exemplo

vou inserir um post com a categoria com id = 2 , então o nome do meu post vai ser algo que eu ja tenha definido mais o restante passado pelo form , tipo para os posts com categoria de id = 2  o nome desses posts vai ter "REDIO" + valor passado pelo form , meio confuso tem como fazer algo assim ?

Answer (score 2):

```
if($categoria->id==2)
   $post->titulo='REDIO'.$_POST['form']['titulo'];
```

UPDATE:

```
//O seu post deve conter o id da categoria, logo
$idCategoria = $_POST['form']['id_categoria'];
//recupera do banco de dados o OBJETO categoria
$categoria = getCategoriaBancoDeDados($idCategoria);
//O objeto categoria tem o atributo prefixo
$post->titulo=$categoria->prefixo.$_POST['form']['titulo'];
```

Banco de dados

```html
<table style="border:1px solid #ccc">
  <tr style="border:1px solid #ccc">
    <th>categorias</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border:1px solid #ccc">id</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border:1px solid #ccc">prefixo</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border:1px solid #ccc">[outros campos]</td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Amigo  boa ideia mas n da certo pro meu problema  , porque eu quero que identifique o id da categoria e assim busque o prefixo  , pois vai ser vários

Comment: confere agora .

Answer (score 1):

Não entendi muito bem, você quer que dependendo do `id`, o título da postagem tenha um prefixo pré-determinado?

Por exemplo:

```
Título original = "Alguma coisa"
ID = 1
Prefixo = "TESTE"

Titulo final = "TESTEAlguma coisa"
```

Seria isso?

Se for, seria interessante você criar uma tabela de prefixos, contendo o ID e o prefixo que você quer utilizar, depois fazer um `SELECT`para retornar o prefixo do ID solicitado, para só então fazer o `INSERT`.

Comment: Olá  amigo  é isso msm , porém nao consigo compreender como eu faria isso poderia dar um exemplo  prático ou descrever melhor esse procedimento  ?